# Creating Excel file: no data returned requires .ToList(), data returned precludes .ToList()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem where I seem to be caught in a data conflict. I am trying to use NuGet [Canducci EXCEL](https://github.com/netdragoon/tutorial/blob/master/READMEEXCEL.md) to help me create an excel file. If there is no data being returned, I need to leave off a `.ToList()` or the attempt errors out. If there is data being returned, it errors out unless I have the `.ToList()`.

So my code is thus:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public FileContentResult Report1ToExcel(Report1ToExcelViewModel viewModel) {
  byte[] fileByte = null;
  using(ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext()) {
    var report1ToExcel = (
      from co in db.Company
      where co.CompanyStatusId == new Guid("A91DAA0F-3ADF-E511-8265-14FEB5FBEAE8")
      join cy in db.Cycle on co.CompanyId equals cy.CompanyId into cycles
      from cd in cycles.OrderByDescending(cy => cy.CycleDate).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
      where cd.CycleDate >= viewModel.Report1ToExcelDateFrom
      where cd.CycleDate <= viewModel.Report1ToExcelDateTo
      orderby co.InitialContact.InitialContactType descending
      select new Report1ExcelData {
        CompanyName = co.CompanyName,
        InitialContactType = co.InitialContact.InitialContactType,
        CompanyRegion = co.Region.RegionName,
        NumberOfEmployees = co.NumberOfEmployees,
        IndustryType = co.Industry.IndustryName,
        HowHeard = co.HowHeard.HowHeardType,
        ProspectingScore = co.ProspectingScore
      }
    );
    fileByte = report1ToExcel.ToExcelByte();
  }
  return File(fileByte, "application/excel", "ReportOne.xlsx");
}
```

See the `fileByte =` at the end? If I have it as,

```
fileByte = report1ToExcel.ToExcelByte();
```

Then if there is an empty dataset returned it works, but if there is a populated dataset returned it throws the error message,

```
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
```

If I use,

```
fileByte = report1ToExcel.ToList().ToExcelByte();
```

Then it only works if data is being returned. If data is not being returned, I get the error message,

```
Enumeration has either not started or has already finished.
```

It seems that I have a “damned if I do, damned if I don’t” situation.

Please keep in mind that I am filtering via a very specific date range in a subtable, for which multiple entries can exist for a company but I want to target only the latest entry. Hence the `.Take(1).DefaultOrEmpty()`. I need to be able to handle a situation where a date range may bring back absolutely NOTHING in a data set.

Comment: in your connection string please see if you are having `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` if its not there then please try to keep it for the first approach

Comment: I am almost positive that this string is not in the connectionstring. Are you saying I should put it in? Or should I check `report1ToExcel` to see if it has content first, to throw an error message to the user if there is no data? And if I do the check, is it enough to do `report1ToExcel != null` to throw the content-positive case?

Comment: please try to keep it and check once again

Comment: Sorry, no change with or without it being in the connectionstring.